# Auto reindex 'Product Flat Data' and refresh cache 'Blocks HTML output'

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, cache, cron, reindex

When I edit something on a product, Magento always ask, reindex 'Product Flat Data' and refresh cache 'Blocks HTML output'

I manually process those whenever I edit but it's very annoying when I have to edit my product often. I give up to those two task since I have to do it later again

**Is there any way automatically reindex 'Product Flat Data' and refresh cache 'Blocks HTML output' every few hours? like using cronjob (then how to setup?)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento has a class that specifically handles command line scripts.  The Magento bootstrap can be handled via the Shell Abstract script inside of your `shell/` folder.

```
<?php

include_once 'abstract.php';

class JohnG_Shell_Cron extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {

    public function run() {
        $this->_clearindex();
        $this->_clearCache();
    }

    protected function _clearindex() {
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_flat');
        $process->reindexAll();
    }

    protected function _clearCache() {
        Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean('block_html');
    }
}
```

Now setup your cron like this:

```
0 0-23/2 * * * php -f /path/to/your/magento/shell/johngscript.php
```

Comment: The script above won't do anything unless you load the class and run it. You need to add

$shell = new JohnG_Shell_Cron();
$shell->run();

Comment: I had to use Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

Create a php file called "refresh.php".

```
<?php
require dirname(__FILE__).'/app/Mage.php'; // It's good to pull the entire path for a cron.
Mage::app();
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_flat')->reindexAll(); // Run Flat Product reindex
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean('block_html'); // Flush Block cache
```

You can then call this file in crontab whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by create shell script.

At first line you need add magento bootrap file Mage.php.then set store as admin

```
<?php
require_once "YOUR_MAGENTODIR/app/Mage.php"
Mage::app("admin"); //set store as admin
umask();

/* reindex */
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('atalog_product_flat');
$process->reindexAll();
/* Clear Catch */

Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean('block_html');
```